# What are these IANA IP addresses doing in my firewall settings?

Tags: ip, firewall

I'm running a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, which is connected to the WAN via a VPN service.

I was monitoring my Ethernet network traffic `eth0` using `iftop` to make sure the traffic goes through `vpn` instead of `eth0`.

In my `eth0` traffic I see traffic connecting to the IP addresses `224.0.0.251` and `239.255.255.250`. An address lookup reveals that they belong to the *Internet Assigned Numbers Authority*.

Strangely enough, when listing `iptables -L`, I see that my `ufw` firewall has 'accept' rules for these IP addresses.

```
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have never added these rules myself since installing `ufw` or ever before – so I'm wondering what these are and if they should safely remain where they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I see traffic connecting to the IP addresses `224.0.0.251` and `239.255.255.250`

`224.0.0.251` and `239.255.255.250` are [Multicast addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address):

> A multicast address is a logical identifier for a group of hosts in a computer network, that are available to process datagrams or frames intended to be multicast for a designated network service.
>
> Multicast addressing can be used in the Link Layer (Layer 2 in the OSI model), such as Ethernet multicast, and at the Internet Layer (Layer 3 for OSI) for Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) or Version 6 (IPv6) multicast.

Further information is provided below, but this kind of activity is normal.

---

#### What is `224.0.0.251`?

`224.0.0.251` is a [Multicast DNS (mDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) address.

> the multicast Domain Name System (mDNS) resolves host names to IP addresses within small networks that do not include a local name server.
>
> It is a zero-configuration service, using essentially the same programming interfaces, packet formats and operating semantics as the unicast Domain Name System (DNS).

Source [Multicast DNS (mDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)

> I've seen those types of requests before - those certainly look much
>   like [Bonjour / mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) requests to me. They use multicast IP address
>   224.0.0.251 and port 5353.
>
> The most likely source for this is [Apple iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1601), which as you
>   know comes pre-installed on Mac computers and is a popular install on
>   Windows machines.
>
> UPDATE: if this is a Linux box (not a Mac or Windows box), that's
>   probably the [Avahi daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) then. Its [ZeroConf/Bonjour
>   compatible](http://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf). Its installed by default, but if you don't use DNS-SD
>   or mDNS, it can be disabled.

Source [what is the multicast doing on 224.0.0.251?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251) answer by [suman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203129/suman)

---

#### What is `239.255.255.250`?

`239.255.255.250` is a [Simple Service Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) address.

> The Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP) is a network protocol based on the Internet Protocol Suite for advertisement and discovery of network services and presence information.
>
> It accomplishes this without assistance of server-based configuration mechanisms, such as the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) or the Domain Name System (DNS), and without special static configuration of a network host.
>
> SSDP is the basis of the discovery protocol of Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) and is intended for use in residential or small office environments.

Source [Service Location Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)

---

#### Further Reading

- [what is the multicast doing on 224.0.0.251?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251)